# Como obtener horas extra en Jquery

Tags: c#, html, jquery, mvc, script

Tengo un html con Jquery pero quiero obtener las horas extra con el siguiente codigo, en mi html tengo 4 input type="time":

1. para el ingreso (**✓**).
2. para la salida (**✓**).
3. obtiene las horas trabajadas (**✓**).
4. las horas extra, que se obtendría de las horas trabajadas - la jornada laborar de 9 horas diarias. (***X***)

El detalle esta en que obtiene las horas mas no los minutos, como puedo completar mi código?

```
<script>
    function HorasExtra() {
        var HrsTrabajadas = $("#HrsTrabajadas").val();
        var HrsExtra = 9;  //esto representa una jornada laboral de 9 horas diarias
        var HrsExtraTrabajadas = $("#HrsExtra").val();

        var Resultado = parseFloat(HrsTrabajadas) - parseFloat(HrsExtra);
        $("#HrsExtra").val(Resultado);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué formato tienen los valores de hora? seria muy bueno que lo agregaras a tu pregunta en **editar**

Comment: tal vez deberías trabajar con minutos en lugar de horas, contado los minutos es mas fácil luego transformarlo en horas (60 min = 1 hora), así si se trabajo 630 mins equivale a 10 hrs y 30 min, menos las 9 hrs de jornada laboral = 1 hr 30 min de horas extra. espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Que formato tiene el campo "#HrsTrabajadas" y "#HrsExtra"?. Te recomiendo que trabajes en función del formato que utilices. Con esto me refiero si por ejemplo tu formato es solo horas (HH) realices la operación en horas, pero si es HH:mm trabajes en función de los minutos y si es HH:mm:ss trabajes en función de los segundos. Resumidamente trabaja con la menor unidad de tiempo que soporte el formato utilizado, es mejor, te evitas dolores de cabeza con el manejo de los decimales y obtienes más precisión en los cálculos. Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno encontré la siguiente solución, espero sirva para posteriores consultas, gracias:

```
<script>
function CalcularHorasExtra() {
    var hora_inicio = $('#Jornada').val();
    var hora_final = $('#HrsTrabajadas').val();

    // Expresión regular para comprobar formato
    var formatohora = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;

    // Si algún valor no tiene formato correcto sale
    if (!(hora_inicio.match(formatohora)
          && hora_final.match(formatohora))) {
        return;
    }

    // Calcula los minutos de cada hora
    var minutos_inicio = hora_inicio.split(':')
      .reduce((p, c) => parseInt(p) * 60 + parseInt(c));
    var minutos_final = hora_final.split(':')
      .reduce((p, c) => parseInt(p) * 60 + parseInt(c));

    // Si la hora final es anterior a la hora inicial sale
    if (minutos_final < minutos_inicio) return;

    // Diferencia de minutos
    var diferencia = minutos_final - minutos_inicio;

    // Cálculo de horas y minutos de la diferencia
    var horas = Math.floor(diferencia / 60);
    var minutos = diferencia % 60;

    $('#HrsExtra').val(horas + ':'
      + (minutos < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutos);
}

$('#HrsTrabajadas').change(CalcularHorasExtra);
$('#Salida').change(CalcularHorasExtra);
CalcularHorasExtra();
```